# Add users to projects they don't belong to? Postgres / Vue JS

Tags: postgresql, vue.js

I've got three tables,

User:

```
id        email
1         greg@yahoo.com
2         erik@gmail.com
3         joey@friends.com
4         omar@thewire.com
```

Projects:

```
id        name
1         Falcon
2         Dragon
3         Phoenix
```

And UserProjects (junction table to see which user belongs to what project):

```
id        user_id        project_id
1         1              1
2         1              2
3         2              2
```

I've set up a REST API for my frontend to query and I wish to display this information in a table that admins can edit/update. Basically, the admins should be able to add users to projects, I'm just not entirely sure how to display the data on the frontend - when the admin goes to a specific project page, they should be able to add users that *does not* already exist for that specific project. Eg, if I were to display project `Falcon`, the admin should be able to assign `joey@friends.com` and `omar@thewire.com` since they don't belong to the project already.

This might not be the ideal way of doing things, if not - how would you guys recommend I structure it? Is this a job my DB should handle, or should I somehow filter that out on the frontend?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the tip. After playing around a bit with `.filter` on the frontend and some queries on the backend, I came to the conclusion that this will be easier to maintain:

```
SELECT id, email
FROM "user"
WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT user_id FROM userprojects WHERE project_id = 1)
```

I'll replace the `project_id = 1` with whatever project ID I'll need to query for.

If this is considered a bad query, let me know.

Answer (score -1):

For things like this, you would generally filter your list on the frontend. 
That way, you don't need an addition API call on your backend and it's just simpler/faster.